# Migration from Jetty 6 to Jetty 8

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I use jetty6 in simple application as embedded servlet container. I decided to update it to Jetty 8.
In jetty 6 it was pretty simple to start the server:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
Context context = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS);
context.addServlet(MyServlet.class, "/communication-service");
server.start();
```

but it doesn't work in Jetty8. 
Unfortunately I can't find any simple example for this version. Can't instantiate Context with error

```
an enclosing instance that contains
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.Context is required
```

because now it is an inner class and also no such constructor.

Most examples are for jetty 6 and 7.
Could you please provide simple example how to start servlet at jetty 8?

Comment: Your question is short on detail. What doesn't work? Which line causes the problem? Is there a stack trace when you try and run?

Comment: I've got the same problem in some of my Jetty 6 code. I had two `Context`s that take the server as a parameter. In Jetty 8 the pattern seems to be inverted, in that you have a `setHandler` method in the server (for a single handler). But none of the documentation seems to address how you migrate code with more than one Context attached to the same Server. Is this a situation where you're meant to use a Context Handler Collection?

Comment: Ah, worked it out. Tim's answer below is all I needed, with multiple `handler.addServlet` calls for each servlet.

Answer (score 13):

This is the Jetty 8 equivalent to your code. It's still just as simple as it was before, however the API has changed slightly.

If this isn't working for you, then you probably have a classpath issue - Jetty 8 is separated into a lot of independent jar files, and you will need a number of them. At the very least you need:

- jetty-continuation
- jetty-http
- jetty-io
- jetty-security
- jetty-server
- jetty-servlet
- jetty-util
- servlet-api

If you have those jars, then this code should work fine:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;

public class Jetty8Server {
    public static class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.getWriter().write(getClass().getName() + " - OK");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        handler.setContextPath("/"); // technically not required, as "/" is the default
        handler.addServlet(MyServlet.class, "/communication-service");
        server.setHandler(handler);
        server.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jetty is nowadays part of Eclipse. The documentation [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) is for Jetty 7 but claims it should work for Jetty 8. There's an example of using servlets towards the end of the page.

Comment: This example doesn't work too. no such classes as ServletContextHandler and ServletHolder

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong as the Jetty 8 Javadoc has these classes listed.

Comment: I've added maven dependency org.eclipse.jetty jetty-server 8.1. What can be wrong there? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12053587/jetty1.png

Comment: Your screenshot shows you are missing the jetty-servlet JAR, which is where those classes are in my download of Jetty 8. I have way more JARs in my download than you have.